# Media Player App Crush only when is running on device, not when is connected to eclipse

Tags: java, android

I have a media player app created that has a strange behavior, when i connect the device to the 
eclipse and i start the app no error showed in the logCat or debug mode, even if i just do a simple run with device connected, app won't crush.

LogCat error

```
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not        

execute method of the activity
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at  

android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3838)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at      

android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at    
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at    
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  

Method)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584): Caused by: 

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3833)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    ... 11 more
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584): Caused by: 

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

com.an3rey.musicplayer.MusicService.playSong(MusicService.java:167)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    at 

com.an3rey.musicplayer.MainActivity.songPicked(MainActivity.java:181)
09-19 10:02:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(24584):    ... 14 more
```

Here is the Service class that keep the Media Player

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,     

MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private int songPos;
private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
private String songTitle=";";
private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
private static boolean shuffle=false;
private Random rand;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //initialize the position
    songPos = 0;
    //create player
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    initMusicPlayer();
    rand=new Random();

}
public boolean setShuffle(){
      if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
      else shuffle=true;
      return shuffle;
    }



public void setList(ArrayList<Song> songsList){
    songs = songsList;
}
public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
      MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
      }
    }

public void initMusicPlayer() {
    mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    //set the listeners
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return musicBind;
}
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    stopForeground(true);
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release(); 
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()>0){
        mp.reset();
        playNext();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    mp.reset();
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
      mp.start();
      Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

      builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
        .setTicker(songTitle)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentTitle("Playing")
        .setContentText(songTitle);
      Notification not = builder.build();

      startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);

}
public void playPrev(){
      songPos--;
      if(songPos<0) songPos=songs.size()-1;
      playSong();
    }
//skip to next
public void playNext(){
    if(shuffle){
        int newSong = songPos;
        while(newSong==songPos){
          newSong=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
        }
        songPos=newSong;
      }
      else{
        songPos++;
        if(songPos>=songs.size()) songPos=0;
      }
  playSong();
}
    public int getPosn(){
      return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getDur(){
      return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    public boolean isPng(){
      return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public void pausePlayer(){
      mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void seek(int posn){
      mediaPlayer.seekTo(posn);
    }

    public void go(){
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    public void playSong(){
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    Song playSong = songs.get(songPos);
    songTitle = playSong.getTitle();
    long currSong = playSong.getId();
    Uri trackUri =  
    ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, currSong);



    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),trackUri);
    } catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}
public void setSong(int songIndex){
      songPos=songIndex;
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  stopForeground(true);
  mediaPlayer.stop();
  mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

}

This is my MainActivity witch is bounded with the Service from where i control the Media Player

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    MediaPlayerControl {

private ArrayList<Song> songList;
private ListView songView;
SongAdapter songAdapter;
Menu menu;

private MusicService musicService;
private Intent playIntent;
private boolean musicBound = false;

private boolean paused = false, playbackPaused = false;

private MusicController controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_view);
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

    // getSongList();
    new LoadListAsyncTask().execute();
    setController();


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    paused = true;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    controller.hide();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (paused) {
        setController();
        paused = false;
        controller.show();
    }

}

// connect to the service
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder) service;
        // get service
        musicService = binder.getService();
        // pass list
        musicService.setList(songList);
        musicBound = true;

    }
};

private void sortListSong() {

    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Song a, Song b) {

            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

}

public class LoadListAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Song>> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Song> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = contentResolver.query(musicUri, null, null,
                null, null);

        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = musicCursor
                        .getLong(musicCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                String titleString = musicCursor
                        .getString(musicCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String artist = musicCursor
                        .getString(musicCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                songList.add(new Song(id, titleString, artist));

            } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return songList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Song> result) {
        songList = result;
        sortListSong();
        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(MainActivity.this, songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}

public void songPicked(View view) {
    musicService.setSong(view.getId());
      musicService.playSong();
      if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
      }
      controller.show(0);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_end:
        stopService(playIntent);
        musicService = null;
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    case R.id.action_shuffle:
        if(musicService.setShuffle())
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.random_on));
        else {
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.random_off));
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(playIntent);
    musicService = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void setController() {
    controller = new MusicController(this);
    controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();

        }

    }, new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playPrev();

        }

    });
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.song_view));
}

// play next
private void playNext() {
    musicService.playNext();
      if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
      }
      controller.show(0);
}

// play previous
private void playPrev() {
    musicService.playPrev();
      if(playbackPaused){
        setController();
        playbackPaused=false;
      }
    controller.show(0);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    musicService.go();

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    playbackPaused=true;
    musicService.pausePlayer();

}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPng()) {
        return musicService.getDur();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPng()) {
        return musicService.getPosn();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    musicService.seek(pos);

}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    if (musicService != null && musicBound)
        return musicService.isPng();
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

When i run the app without device being connected to the eclipse environment, i have a crush when i press a song in listView, approximately 2-3 crashes at 5 restarts of the app.
I think the problem could be with the mediaPlayer release,stop,clear states not being performed  when the app is closed.(but i double check the states, and everything seems to be allright).
But how can i catch this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your logcat and your code... and dont write such a _BIG_ paragraph.....without posting any code.....

Comment: What's line MusicService.java:167?

Comment: line:167 on me is right before onDestroy overridden method.